# How can different devices represented by the same device file be automatically mounted to different mounting points?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, automounting

In Ubuntu, even if different block devices  (e.g. an external hard drive and a flash drive) are  represented by the same device file (e.g. `/dev/sdb1`) one after another, they are automatically mounted to different mounting points (e.g. `/media/b/mydrive` and `/media/b/myflashdrive`). How is that achieved? How does Ubuntu know the "name" of each device and use that "name" to name its mounting point? (`/etc/fstab` doesn't cover these plug-in devices.)

How can I simulate that?  When manually mounting a block device, I run

```
sudo mkdir /media/b/mountingpoint1
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /media/b/mountingpoint1
sudo umount /media/b/mountingpoint1
sudo rmdir /media/b/mountingpoint1
```

If I detach the device and then attach a different block device, the new device will be again represented by the same device file `/dev/sdb1`, and the above command will mount it to the same mounting point `/media/b/mountingpoint1`. I need a way to name the mounting points differently for different devices.

Comment: Where it gets the names is anyone guess, but there are filesystem/volume labels.

Answer (score 3):

> are represented by the same device file (e.g. /dev/sdb1)

The trick is that they are **not** represented by the same device file: In addition to that primary device file, which contains letters and numbers managed by the kernel, you also have symlinks in `/dev/disk/by-*` which, for example, contain the volume name of the filesystem, the vendor and model of the harddrive, or the device path.

And it's those symlinks that you should use inside `/etc/fstab`, not `/dev/sdb1` etc.

Answer (score 2):

> (e.g. `/media/b/mydrive` and `/media/b/myflashdrive`). How is that achieved? How does Ubuntu know the "name" of each device and use that "name" to name its mounting point? (`/etc/fstab` doesn't cover these plug-in devices.)

Mounting of removable devices is done by UDisks which also creates the mountpoint for them which is always (on Ubuntu) in format `/media/<user>/<unique_id>`. The last part is either filesystem label or UUID if the filesystem doesn't have a label. Removable disks and drives are usually preformatted and the partition labeled by the vendor (e.g. my Kingston flash drive has the VFAT partition labeled as `KINGSTON`).

You can get the label (and UUID) for your devices with `lsblk -f`.

If you want to mount a device manually (not from GUI) and achieve the same effect you can use `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb1`.

And if you (in the future) use `fstab` for automounting you should always use UUID (`UUID=`) instead of `/dev/sdb1`.